# Related to Concat multiple XML tags with su

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

How do I achieve below requirement in XSLT 1.0, any suggestion will help me a lot. I am beginner in this. Need help.

Q1. If address_line1 > 40, then first 40 character should be displayed and remaining to be overflow to Address_line2, then address_line2 data to be displayed.

Q2. if address_Line2 > 40, then first character should be displayed and remaining to be overflow to addrss_line3. So on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should add some more information on what do you have as inputs and what did you try so far in order to get accurate output.